# HTML5 color input Event firing on mouse up in the color picker

Tags: html, events, html5-canvas, jquery-events

I would like to know if there is an event that fires on mouse up in the color picker in the HTML5 input color, I'm using the color input to change a fabricjs canvas color and changing it on drag kills the performance, here is the code that I'm using:

```
$('#multiply-color').change(function() {
    applyFilterValue(13, 'color', this.value);
});
```

a simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8yhtLxc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
(function (el, timeout) {
    var timer;
    el.bind("input", function () {

        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = setTimeout(function () {

            jQuery('#main').css('background-color', jQuery(el).val());
        }, timeout);
    });
})($("#colorinput"), 200);
```

Comment: I tried but this doesn't seem to work for me, the changed event is never triggred : http://jsfiddle.net/7yvfkcdn/

Comment: can you please remove the not working answer for future users

Comment: and (this).val() doesn't work because you are in the function you could use (el).val() to avoid calling the jquery selector